# asp buttonimage alternate text not visible

Tags: asp.net

I've a problem with asp:image and asp:imagebutton alternate text: it's not visible when I move the mouse over the image. I declared the object in that way:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonStatus" 
ImageUrl='<%# IIF(Eval("Active")=1,"../images/folders/actived.png","../images/folders/deactivate.png")%>' CommandName="ChangeStatus" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id_repository") %>' OnCommand="FolderCommand" 
Enabled = '<% #iif(mySecurity.Admin=1, "True", "False") %>' Width="24px" AlternateText="Change the status"
runat="server" />
```

and for asp:image

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="url_groups" NavigateUrl="~/action/Group_manager.aspx?action=2">                                                 
    <asp:Image id="img_groups" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/folders/group_config.png" AlternateText="Group manager"
    EnableViewState="false" ImageAlign="Middle" Width="32px" CssClass="navigation" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Could you help me? I tried to search on web but I wasn't able to find any post or suggestion to fix that problem

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Hi Oded, it's not clear your question, could you explain better, please?

Comment: You have posted the .aspx - when you view in the browser (view source), what does it look like?

Comment: <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder_contents$folderList$ctl02$ButtonStatus" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_contents_folderList_ctl02_ButtonStatus" src="../images/folders/actived.png" alt="Cambia lo stato della cartella" style="width:24px;border-width:0px;" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing up the alt attribute with the title attribute. Alt is shown when the user doesn't accept images and for screen readers whereas the title attribute is shown as tool tip when you hover the image.

Comment: Most browsers will show a "tool-tip" when an "alt" attribute is present on an image.

Comment: @Oded, unfortunately FireFox isn't one of those browsers. Need to use ToolTip for FF.

Comment: @waldenl Or you could just set the title tag see http://www.petefreitag.com/item/266.cfm

Comment: @Justin, true, except on <asp:ImageButton> and sim'lar controls which don't expose a "Title" attribute.

Comment: @WaldenL, the asp ToolTip property renders the "title" attribute, and the AlternateText property renders the "alt" attribute (because Microsoft had to rename everything just a little bit...). MartinSteel's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's browser dependent whether the alt text gets shown when you mouse over an image.  If you set the ToolTip parameter on a .NET Image or ImageButton it will render a title attribute which shows across pretty much every browser.

Here's an example from a site I'm currently working on:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="ReplyLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("SrcAddr", "~/msp/send.aspx?to={0}") %>'>
    <asp:Image ID="ReplyIcon" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/email_go.png" AlternateText="Reply" ToolTip="Reply" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```